# spring, wicket: atmosphere Eventbus nullpointerexception when testing

Tags: spring, testing, wicket, atmosphere, wicket-1.6

I am using following code:

```
private WicketTester tester;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
@Autowired
private LDBApplication ldbApplication;

@Before
public void setUp() {
  tester = new WicketTester(ldbApplication);
  tester.getApplication().getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(tester.getApplication(), applicationContext, true));
}
```

I am initializing an Eventbus in the LDBApplication init() method:

```
@Override
protected void init() {
  super.init();
  eventBus = new EventBus(this);
}
```

I get a nullpointer exception when this happens:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.wicket.atmosphere.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:113)
at com.phoenixbv.wicket.http.PxWebApplication.init(PxWebApplication.java:55)
at com.phoenixbv.ldb_wicket.LDBApplication.init(LDBApplication.java:67)
at org.apache.wicket.Application.initApplication(Application.java:818)
at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.<init>(BaseWicketTester.java:287)
at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.BaseWicketTester.<init>(BaseWicketTester.java:231)
at org.apache.wicket.util.tester.WicketTester.<init>(WicketTester.java:184)
at com.phoenixbv.ldb_wicket.scan.test.ScanServiceTest.setUp(ScanServiceTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I know this has got to do something with the atmosphere.xml file. However, I cannot just change the web.xml file, because I am not using this one, because I am only testing. Anyone got any other solution?

Comment: Please provide the exact exception and its stacktrace, otherwise it won't be possible to help you.

Comment: I updated my post with stracktrace

Comment: Please provide your web.xml too.

Comment: for testing the web.xml is not used, right??